# AutoMapper issue- Automap the DTO,Viewmodel if DTO contains another DTo

Tags: c#, automapper

Automap the dto with subDto

```
class productsDTO
{
    public int id;
    public AddressDTO DeliveryAddress; 
}

Class productsViewModel
{
    public int id;
    public AddressViewModel DeliveryAddress; 
}
```

Here, I have one dto class. I just want to auto map the dTo class into view model. In DTO class has AddressDTo that has to be automatically mapped AddressViewModel in productsViewModel.

If anyone have solution just post

```
 var products = [some objects]; 
    products.ForEach(a =>
    { 
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    { 
    cfg.CreateMap<ProductsDTO, ProductsViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DeliveryAddress, opts =>opts.Ignore())
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => {
    dest.DestinationAddress = 
    Mapper.Map(src.DeliveryAddress,dest.DeliveryAddress);
     }); 
    });
     IMapper iMapper = config.CreateMapper(); 
    var productList = iMapper.Map<ProductsDTO, ProductsViewModel>(a); 
products.add(productList) 
});
```

This code produce an error like this : "*Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.*"

Comment: you need a second mapping defined between AddressDTO and AddressViewModel. Then when you map between productsDTO and productsViewModel it will automatically map those properties as well.

Comment: can u explain it with example code

Comment: You created a mapping between productsDTO and productsViewModel, (using CreateMap), yes? So, do exactly the same for the other two classes.

Comment: var products = [some objects];
products.ForEach(a =>{
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>{                    cfg.CreateMap<ProductsDTO, ProductsViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationAddress, opts => opts.Ignore()).AfterMap((src, dest) => {
              dest.DestinationAddress = Mapper.Map(src.DestinationAddress, dest.DestinationAddress);
               });                      
     });
  IMapper iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
  var productList = iMapper.Map<ProductsDTO, ProductsViewModel>(a); 
products.add(productList)});

Comment: is this code correct.but it is produce an error.Can u correct this

Comment: paste code into the question please (use the "edit" button below the question), in comments it's unreadable. And if you have an error you  need to tell us exactly what it is, we can't guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a second mapping, between AddressDTO and AddressViewModel. When when you map between productsDTO and productsViewModel it will automatically map those properties as well, and AutoMapper will know how the mapping should work.

In the same way you mapped productsDTO and productsViewModel, you can map these classes too:

```
cfg.CreateMap<AddressDTO, AddressViewModel>();
```

Also, it should not be necessary to define your mappings multiple times inside a loop, as you are doing now. The mapping is simply a definition, to be used later. It only needs to be specified once. When you want to actually carry out a mapping of two objects, then use `Mapper.Map` - use this as many times as you have objects. It will use the mapping definition you created beforehand. But `cfg.CreateMap` only needs to be called once for each combination of classes. I'm also not sure you need the whole "Ignore" business in your code - it seems redundant to ignore a property and then map it again on the next line. You can also convert all the objects in the products list in a single Map operation.

Something like this should work better, I would think:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{ 
   cfg.CreateMap<ProductsDTO, ProductsViewModel>();
   cfg.CreateMap<AddressDTO, AddressViewModel>();
});
IMapper iMapper = config.CreateMapper(); 

var products = [some objects]; 

List<ProductViewModel> productVMList = iMapper.Map<List<ProductViewModel>>(products);
```

Comment: I tried like this.but it produces an error "Error mapping types.
Mapping types:
ProductsDTO -> ProductViewModel
DTO.Products.ProductsDTO -> ViewModels.ProductViewModel
Type Map configuration:
ProductsDTO -> ProductViewModel
DTO.Products.ProductsDTO -> ViewModels.ProductViewModel
Property:
DestinationAddress"

Comment: According to the code above in your question, you don't have any field called DestinationAddress

Comment: Sorry for that that is DeliveryAddress

Comment: I've added some clarification to my comments in the answer. Although I should comment that `products.add(productList);` makes no sense - you can't add an object of type ProductsViewModel` to a list of type `ProductDTO` (which I assume is what `products` is. Also, why would you want to? Then you'd have a list with what are basically copies of the objects in, but in a different format. Not sure what you're trying to achieve there. But that's not the main point of the question.

Comment: Products is a list of DTO.I don't want to expose my DTO list to View. So that's y i am converting DTO to productList.Productlist i defined it as a list of viewmodels

Comment: But you're adding the items back into `products`, so that statement doesn't match what your code does. `productList` in your code is not actually a list, either. Its a single instance of `ProcuctsViewModel` because that's what the mapping produces. Maybe you actually need to drop the whole ForEach and just do `List<ProductViewModel> productVMList = iMapper.Map<List<ProductViewModel>>(products);`, That would be a lot more logical. Then you have a list of viewmodel objects you can return to your view. I updated the answer to show that.

Comment: No problem. I think you had got some of the concepts a little bit mixed up in your head. Glad it works for you now.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You map AddressDTO and AddressViewModel properties.If you give same property name AutoMapper mapped automatically. If you wanna to map properties with different name, You define which property equals with other...

Docs ;
http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Projection.html

After You will mapped productsDTO and productsViewModel and Everythings work fine.. :)

Comment: i don't want to map each properties. it will automatically map the properties.AddressDTO and AddressViewModel has same properties

Comment: i just add my code here. if it is correct or not. please let me know

Comment: var products = [some objects];
products.ForEach(a =>{
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>{                    cfg.CreateMap<ProductsDTO, ProductsViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationAddress, opts => opts.Ignore()).AfterMap((src, dest) => {
              dest.DestinationAddress = Mapper.Map(src.DestinationAddress, dest.DestinationAddress);
               });                      
     });
  IMapper iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
  var productList = iMapper.Map<ProductsDTO, ProductsViewModel>(a); 
products.add(productList)});

Comment: You mapped base class but this class properties are another class.. You will mapped all sub classes, if you wanna to use it. (AddressDTO - AddressViewModel)